# How to increase qty from current stock in Magento backend?

Tags: magento, product

I need to update product qty from their existing value. For e.g. I have received a qty 100 for each SKU, and I wanted to update all the SKU to be increased by 100 from their current stock value. Does default Magento have this feature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock`. In my opinion, the easiest way to change qty is to use the `correctItemsQty` method from the `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock`.

The code below will help you extract the qty data you need:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app("default"); 

/** @var Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock $model */
$model = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock');
/** @var Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock $resourceModel */
$resourceModel = Mage::getResourceModel('cataloginventory/stock');

/* values: product_id => qty_diff */
$productsForUpdate = array(
    920 => 1,
    921 => 2,
    922 => 3
);

$resourceModel->correctItemsQty($model, $productsForUpdate, '+');
```

The same way, you can extract qty from Stock, just by changing '**+**' to '**-**'

The only disadvantage of this solution is the necessity to get a product ID by SKU.

Also, you can renew the stack status via product import, but that will be a more resource-consuming process.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to your admin
```

Catalog->Manage producrs[ Select all products ] and go right side Action inpute box click the aerow in droupdown, select  'Update attributes' submit than after click inventory  and change your Qty  'Save'

Your task is done...

Comment: Ashish, in that way you just update the number but as i said I want to add the new stock. e.g. If my current stock is 90 and I have new stock 100, when I do via update attribute, it makes stock qty 100 instead of 190(100+90).